# Unity C# UI, Tab menu system. Function is not triggering when i changes from 0 to 1

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I've been working on this code that is for a tab-style system for a UI in Unity. I have written two scripts, *buttonController* that is on a parent object to all the button options, and *buttonSelection*, which is a code on all the buttons on the button Controller object. I've included the code I've written below.

So far, it's kind of working, but I've come up with a funny bug. Whenever the buttonSelected value in the button Controller script goes from 0 to 1, it doesn't trigger the button labeled as 1's function *TurnButtonOn* function until I click it again. I also get the following error message:

NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
ButtonSelection.TurnButtonOn () (at Assets/UI Elements/Code/ButtonSelection.cs:29)
ButtonController.ChangeButtonValue () (at Assets/UI Elements/Code/ButtonController.cs:24)
ButtonController.Start () (at Assets/UI Elements/Code/ButtonController.cs:12)

I think the main problem is with this.transform.GetChild(0).gameObject.SetActive(true);, but I've tried many iterations of this (like gameObject.transform.etc and a couple of other things), but it doesn't seem to change it. Another problem with this bit is that I can't do anything like GameObject.Find, since these two scripts are on multiple objects. Is there anything that I've missed? Thanks :)

I wasn't sure where a goof might be, so I included almost all the code. As a quick rundown, *buttonselection's* ActivateButton function calls on *buttonController's* ChangeButtonValue, which either activates *buttonselection's* TurnButtonOff or TurnButtonOn. Sorry to be a pain :(

```
public class ButtonController : MonoBehaviour

public void ChangeButtonValue()
{
    ButtonSelection[] buttonList = GetComponentsInChildren<ButtonSelection>();
    int i = 0;
    foreach (ButtonSelection bt in buttonList)
    {
        if (i != buttonSelected)
            bt.TurnButtonOff();
        else
            bt.TurnButtonOn();
        i++;
    }
}
```

---

```
public class ButtonSelection : MonoBehaviour
{
public int thisButtonsNumberID;
Image buttonImageOnOff;
public Sprite buttonOnImage;
public Sprite buttonOffImage;
public bool buttonOn =false;

void Start()
{
    //Fetch the Image from the GameObject
    buttonImageOnOff = GetComponent<Image>();
}

public void ActivateButton()
{
    this.transform.parent.GetComponent<ButtonController>().buttonSelected = thisButtonsNumberID;
    this.transform.parent.GetComponent<ButtonController>().ChangeButtonValue();
}

public void TurnButtonOn()
{
    buttonOn = true;
    buttonImageOnOff.sprite = buttonOnImage;
    this.transform.GetChild(0).gameObject.SetActive(true);
}
public void TurnButtonOff()
{
    buttonOn = false;
    buttonImageOnOff.sprite = buttonOffImage;
    this.transform.GetChild(0).gameObject.SetActive(false);
}
```

}

Comment: Hi there! Sorry I haven't the time to give a full answer (and this is not a solution) but in the ChangeButtonValue function, you shouldn't use a foreach there. Change that with a for and use the i properly, addressing bt as buttonList[i].

Comment: Thanks, I had a play around with this, and it seemed to help.

Answer (score 1):

I've come up with a solution, although it is still bombarded with error messages...
in the Controller script I changed the ChangeButtonValue function to this:

```
public void ChangeButtonValue(int buttonSelected)
    {
        if (transform.childCount > 0)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            {
                gameObject.transform.GetChild(i).GetComponent<ButtonSelection>().CheckThisButton(buttonSelected);
            }
        }

    }
```

In the Selection code I added this:

```
public void CheckThisButton(int currentActiveButtonID)
    {
        if (currentActiveButtonID == thisButtonsNumberID) TurnButtonOn();
        else TurnButtonOff();

    }
```

It is by no means perfect, being bombarded with *NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object* and *UnityException: Transform child out of bounds* error messages, but it now kind of works. If anyone has got any suggestions for a more intelligent way to do this, or if anyone happens to spot why this issue was happening in the first place, just let me know :)
I hope this helps anyone else with a similar problem.